# Can you upgrade the pick-10 system?

Tags: call-of-duty-black-ops-2

Call of Duty: Black Ops II uses a 'pick-10' system for online multiplayer.  Meaning of all the guns, attachments, perks, grenades, and wildcards that you have unlocked, you can pick a combination of only 10 to use at one time.

Although I like this idea, it keeps the playing field more level, I would like to be able pick more than 10, to get some more attachments on my secondary, or use all my wildcard slots, etc.

In offline-multiplayer, every gun and attachment is unlocked for you.  Me and my buddies have played split-screen with a 'pick-17' system, where we were able to fully custom classes using every weapon in a combination of 17 items at once.

**Can you increase the max items allowed in online multiplayer?  Do you get an extra one each time you prestige?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, that's why it's called Pick-10.

Answer (score 1):

Online multiplayer is Pick-10, however there have been or may be custom events in some playlists that allow for more picks or less. These come and go and usually don't last long.